# timeline based on dates in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, timeline

I have a list with a few dates per record.
I'd like to create a page with a timeline that shows these dates.
The labels would be something like 'title date1'.
And a filter to show only recent dates (f.e. the last 3 dates + next 10 dates).

Is this possible?
I did find how to create a timeline based on tasks; but we don't use the tasks like that.
I guess I could create a task for every date and based on that create a timeline; but that seems like a lot of trouble?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution or something out of the box?

Comment: I'm dying to learn about programming; but right now I know some javascript and that's it.  So I'm looking for something out of the box or with minimal programming necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I think Tasks with Timeline are the most viable option here. You have some edit and customization possibilities:
[image]
source:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-appearance-of-the-timeline-7e992704-2cf5-4c08-8f49-6a7bb5c92e2c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Another option (not really much different from the first one) is a Timeline webpart:
[image]

Please check out also this [How to use timeline](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/09/how-to-use-the-timeline-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) webpart article.

If the issue with tasks is that you do not want to display them, but just the timeline alone, then this is possible as per instructions [here](https://sharepointdaytoday.com/2014/10/14/displaying-only-the-timeline-of-a-task-list/).

If adding the tasks is cumbersome, you can try adding them by bulk using either datasheet view (check out [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193312/sharepoint-online-cannot-view-lists-in-datasheet-view/193358#193358)) or by Powershell like described in the article [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31382.working-with-multiple-items-using-powershell.aspx).

Comment: The timeline sounds really interesting; but I only have "content search" and "project summary" in my content rollup category. The site was in dutch, i changed the language to english; but still nothing to see. _(sharepoint online part of o365 subscription)_

Comment: This webpart IS available for SharePoint Online. It is available by default for Teamsites, Community, Blog as well as Publishing sites. What template are you using? Is it perhaps a Project Online site? Did you disable some features?

Comment: I've just created new subsites: Teamsite & community; same problem: i don't see the timeline option. I should be admin on the whole sharepoint; the main site is Dutch; but I created the subsites in english.

Comment: What subscription is it? E3?

Comment: Users are mixed business premium & E3; I have an E3 license.

Comment: That issue could be a residue from Business Premium. I am guessing you had that first and then bought extra E3's? Can you check if another global admin has the same issue on a new site collection and if yes, drop a line to Microsoft via service request?