# SharePoint Online : Cannot view lists in DataSheet View

Tags: sharepoint-online, datasheet

I want to view my list as datasheet. But I can't see it anywhere. Some sources that I found in Google said that I need to open in IE. But there's still no DataSheet option

Comment: Check the list advanced settings. See if the ability to edit the list in datasheet view is disabled.

Comment: @Christoffer there is no 'edit in datasheet view' option in advance settings

Comment: Is it a custom list or a special type?

Comment: @Christoffer it's a document library

Comment: A normal document library? And there is no quick edit under the library tab? And you did not found the option " 
Allow items in this document library to be edited using Quick Edit?" under the libraries advanced settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intan, there is no 'DataSheet' button. What you are probably looking for is either Quick Edit or Export to Excel. You can find both of them on the list ribbon:
[image]

[image]

Quick Edit will open a spreadsheet view of your list online. Export to Excel requires desktop Excel and will download the data to a local Excel file.

The same functionality as with 'Quick Edit' can be achieved by clicking 'Edit this list':
[image]

Both 'Quick Edit' and 'Edit this list' will open the list online in a datasheet view that looks like this:
[image]

What you may also be interested in is to create a datasheet view: Ribbon>List>Create view>Datasheet view:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. I think I'm confused between Quick Edit and DataSheet view. Because some tutorial that I found are refer to DataSheet view. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet view doesn't exist in Sharepoint 2013 and up, or the O365 Sharepoint Online.
Quick Edit is now there...but it's not quite the same.  it doesn't have all the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have a client who has had this same problem in SharePoint Online/O365.  Verified that content approval wasn't turned on, point of contact user's browser updated, quick edit feature enabled, etc.  Quick Edit view would allow editing in what we know as datasheet view, and two days ago, the Datasheet view based on the datasheet view option was functional.

My solution:  **create a new view, based on Datasheet option**, same column settings and view order.  The new Datasheet View works as expected, so deleted the previous one - but their settings and configuration was identical.  Since this client has no browser requirements defined (users can use whatever version of whichever browser they prefer), so running down browser settings was not viable.

I'm following along to see if there is a cause that might be flagged down the line.