# Create view, no "Datasheet View" option

Tags: sharepoint-online, datasheet

In only one of my libraries (it's a picture library), there is no "Datasheet View" as an option when creating a new view? (Only standard view and calendar). It's Sharepoint 2013
[image]

I'm trying to follow these instructions https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/193358/51202

Comment: There is already an answer below the link you have shared ."Datasheet view doesn't exist in Sharepoint 2013 and up, or the O365 Sharepoint Online. Quick Edit is now there...but it's not quite the same. it doesn't have all the same functionality."

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions: It does exist. Other lists of the same site have this option. The answer that you quote I think that speaks about the "Quick Edit"  button or something else.

Comment: I think you need the full contribute permissions in order to accomplish this task on that particular list

Comment: Yes agree with TARUN,As I am getting datasheet view for my picture library in SP2013

Comment: @TARUN, I already tried several changes on the permissions with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem with this view was that I had set `Basic Table` as  view style. Changing it to `Default` did the trick...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? It is good you found a solution but others with the same problem can't really solve the issue with the information presented here.

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet view isn't supported with lists with BaseType DocumentLibrary. Only GenericList base type. Basically, there's no datasheet view for document libraries, only lists.

Comment: Are you sure? For example "Documents" default library has it, "Video  Gallery" too. Both these and my list are of "Document Libraries" type, as I see in Designer.

Comment: Just created a new document Library, and I confirm that I can create a Datasheet View. So it's supported.

Comment: Hm, I wasn't able to do it in SharePoint Online. Maybe a certain column is unsupported?